# Can I use a 3.3V linear regulator to level shift a 5V square wave down to a 3.3V square wave?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have an output of a comparator that is a 5V square wave. Can I feed that square wave into a 3.3V regulator to get a 3.3V square wave? The 3.3V regulator I have is the LP2950.

Comment: You could just use a resistor divider

Comment: @EE_socal I don't wan't to use a voltage divider because the voltage I want to shift will not be exactly 5V. It could be a little above or below.

Comment: Yes you could or define voltage tolerance and impedance

Comment: Another option would be resistor in series with a 3.3V Zener diode.

Comment: What is the comparator part number? Does it have an open collector output?

Comment: @Transistor It's an LM393, and it has an open collector output.

Comment: This is not a good idea. Mainly because voltage regulators do not drive to a low voltage. When disabled, or when input power is removed, the output voltage decreases slowly as caps discharge into whatever load is present on the output. Use a level translator (level shifting buffer). Basically, you use a buffer powered from 3.3V, but apply your 5V input to it. There is a whole family of buffers designed to tolerate 5V inputs, even though VCC and the output level are 3.3V.

Comment: Apart from @Transistor's answer - if it's for an MCU the 3.3V ones usually accept lower inputs (STM32 usually down to around 2.3V) and can tolerate somewhat higher too (3.6V for STM32). Have a look at the datasheet.

Answer (score 3):

What is the comparator part number? Does it have an open collector output? – Transistor

> It's an LM393, and it has an open collector output. – Shock-o-lot

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKdNKW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Comparator with 5 V pull-up. (b) Comparator with 3.3 V pull-up.*

[image]

*Figure 2. LM393 internals showing the open-collector output, Q8.*

The open-collector output can be used as a level shifter for this application. It also makes a very simple way of ANDing the outputs of two or more comparators as, for example, in a window comparator circuit.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not an appropriate use of a linear regulator.

1. Linear regulators have a minimum input current. Your comparator may not be able to drive enough current to start up the regulator.
2. Most linear regulators require capacitors on the input and output to guarantee stability. These capacitors will take some time to charge when the output of the comparator goes high, so the "response" from the regulated comparator will be much slower. If the output of the comparator changes frequently enough, the regulator may never turn fully on.
3. Linear regulators generally do not make strong guarantees about their behavior when their input is cut off. If there is no current drawn from the output of the regulator, its output may take some time to go to zero.

Use a resistive voltage divider, or a level shifter IC.

Comment: Or a 3.3 V buffer with 5-V tolerant input.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the square wave is extremely slow (<10Hz), I definitely would not use a linear regulator due to the input and output capacitance required for it to function. Since, as you have said, the voltage may not be "exactly 5V", I would use a 3.3V Zener Diode for this application.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffY2Kz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Zener will have some parasitic capacitance, so give it a go and hopefully your application isn't too high-speed. If your input (whatever the 3.3V square wave is going into) is high-impedance, you can choose a decent size resistor (1k+) and reduce wasted power (which Zener regulators are notorious for).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. As it turns out, the square wave is very low frequency(~2Hz from a heart rate sensor). I tried using the 3.3V regulator but it never gets down to zero volts due to the internal reference. So I can either use your zener circuit, or use an npn transistor with the 3.3V regulator connected to the collector and the 5V square wave connected to the base. Is there any benefit to the latter circuit? Another thing is my comparator is outputs high when idle, and I don't want to waste power when idle.

Comment: @Shock-o-lot I would recommend using a MOSFET as opposed to a BJT. If you use a BJT you will need to have a collector resistor *and* a base resistor to limit the current. A MOSFET will have the exact same operation for this purpose, but will be much more simpler.

As for any "benefit", the obvious thing is that using a transistor means you have a 3.3V power rail. If you use the zener setup, you can ditch the regulator entirely. Another benefit is that if you use transistors, the logic will be inverted - so you will need to have a second transistor to re-invert the logic if this is important.

Answer (score 0):

Voltage regulator weren't meant to be use that way. 
You can use this 
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009